# Referencing the previous row in Spotfire and a value in another column

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to do something that is very simple to do in Excel, but seems very tricky in Spotfire:

Imagine you have the following table:

```
    A
1: 10  
2: 15  
3: 20
```

... and you want to produce the following:

```
    A   B  
1: 10  10  
2: 15  25
3: 20  45
```

In other words, add the current value of A to the previous value of B. If this was Excel, the formula in cell B3 would be `= A3 + B2`... However, I'm not in Excel, I'm using Spotfire... :) Any thoughts?

NB: If it makes any difference to the answer at all, I will need to use the `Intersect()` function in conjunction with this, as there is a categorical column to factor in as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, I have considered the first column as ID

```
ID  A   B
1   10  10
2   15  25
3   20  45
```

```
If(Sum([A]) over (AllPrevious([ID])) is null,sum([A]) over ([ID]),Sum([A]) over (AllPrevious([ID])))
```

Comment: This is very useful. Can you explain what the `sum([A]) over ([ID])` does / how it works, as I haven't seen that in a custom expression before? -- i.e. the use of an OVER statement without the inclusion of e.g. AllPrevious, First, etc

Comment: it's similar to using `Intersect()` with only one parameter. it will sum all values for [A] with a given [ID]

Comment: @Jon- instead of using IF statement, sum([A]) over (AllPrevious([ID])) should also work.